# How to set the testID and the accessibilityLabel together with React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, appium

I am having a weird issue setting the testID together with the accessibilityLabel for my React Native application, the purpose of this is to have the "accessibility id" on iOS and Android app visible with Appium Inspector (Appium Desktop), the issue is the following:

1. If the testID is set together with the accessibilityLabel, the iOS app does not show the "accessibility id" in the component but the android app does.
2. If I only set the testID, the iOS app shows correctly the "accessibility id" in the component but for android is missing the "accessibility id" in the component.
3. If I only set the accessibilityLabel, the Android app shows the "accessibility id" correctly but the iOS app is missing.

here is the code that I have

```
export enum TestID {
  ImageLogo = 'ImageLogo'
}

export const LogoComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Image
      testID={TestID.ImageLogo}
      accessibilityLabel={TestID.ImageLogo}
    />
  );
};
```

Also, I've tried to setup the accessible attribute to false/true without success
The React Native version that I am using is the following:

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.2",
```

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade to React Native 0.64 - it has proper support for `testID` on Android. Note that because `testID` on Android maps to the `resource-id` of the View, Appium requires your testIDs to be formatted in the canonical style for resource IDs: `<package>:id/<identifier>`.

In our app, we do the following for our test IDs:

```
<Text testID="test:id/hello-text">Hello</Text>
```

If you're using the `wd` library to talk to appium, you can then do:

```
await driver.elementById("test:id/hello-text")
```

Comment: Wow this answer saved me. One thing I missed at first with wd is I needed to change all of my elementByAccessibilityId calls to elementById.

Comment: can we do it with react-native 0.63.4 ?

Comment: @pravchuk Unfortunately no, `testID` on Android is not accessible to Appium until React Native 0.64.

Comment: This problem is not actual starting from react-native@0.65.x!!!
Display the testID as the resource-id for black-box testing frameworks ( #381fb3 by @jdeff) ;CHANGELOG: https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#android-specific-9

Comment: @DAVID_ That change was back-ported to the 0.64 branch. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/70ba9acfe97c05a04c1f0fb7a8f48f4c2d8c7072

Comment: well, I'm trying to use it since 2 days, but appium inspector simply does not recognize any id in an element. If I use `testID={'myapp.staging:id/identifier'}`and i run appium inspector, no clue; while if I use `accessibilityLabel={'myapp.staging:id/identifier'}` it works. In my `package.json` I have the line `"react-native": "^0.64.1"`. Are you sure it works with react-native 0.64?

Comment: update: this change works ONLY with 0.64, and NOT with other versions (0.64.1, etc.). This because the official update is from 0.65 onwards ( https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md ). They added the commit to 0.64 exclusively.

Comment: We use `react-native` 0.68.5, and we still have a problem if we don't set the `accessibilityLabel`, this is more than annoying as `accessibilityLabel` is read by screenreaders. Is there an issue reported in react native project and will it be solved ? Currently the proposed fix to add a prefix to `test:id/` does not help we are unable to click on the button..

Answer (score 5):

Try using the below testID for your components:

```
export default function testID(id) {
  return Platform.OS === 'android'
    ? { accessible: true, accessibilityLabel: id }
    : { testID: id }
}

<Text {...testID('hello-text')} >hello world</Text>
```

Comment: This is not accurate anymore, you can just use accessibilitylabel and accessible true e.g. `accessible accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel} />` https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#accessibilitylabel

Comment: That's what did the trick to me using React Native 0.66 + Webdriverio

Answer (score 2):

This question was hard for me too.
But the response is:

Use `test:id/` in front of your ID, like this

[image: configure testID]

And later, use that `test:id/identifier` for select the element into the test.

[image]

Comment: Hello! It's awesome that you spent so much time on providing a high quality answer. However, keep in mind that Stack Overflow generally isn't a place where people are compensated for their answers besides earning rep and badges. See the meta post regarding self promotion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the issue that the element and IDs do not appear in Appium.

the solution is using replace @react-navigation/stack to **@react-navigation/native-stack**

for more details:
1-https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/14825#issuecomment-1690850085

2-https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/